# Error while handling multiple txt files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, large-data

I'm constructing a program to search all .xml inside a folder setted by user (Source folder) and copy all these files to another folder (Destination folder).

[image: Form1]

My program is able to search all XML within all sub folders from (Source folder), the result returns around 5000 files that are placed on a list, this list is worked later by a function, but he can only work with 31 files, then appears "not responding "and the debugger shows that the program is staying a long time in the execution.

Here is my code:

Button action:

```
private void btnCopiarSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string name in listFileNames)
    {
         if (readXML(name ))
         {
              tbArquivo.Text = name ; //Feedback textbox, tell the current filename
         }                    
    }
    pbStatus.Increment(50); 
    cbFinal.Checked = true; //Feedback checkBox, to tell user that the task is over.
}
```

Function ReadXML

```
public bool readXML(string name)
{
    //foreach (string nome in listaArquivos) 
    //{  //I tried to the foreach inside, but nothing Works.

    try
    {
        string text = null;
        string readBuffer = File.ReadAllText(name);
        text = readBuffer.Aggregate(text, (current, b) => current + b);
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Byte[] textobytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);

        if (!File.Exists(destino))
        {
            string destinoComNomeArquivo = destino + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(nome);
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(destinoComNomeArquivo))
            {
                foreach (byte textobyte in textobytes)
                {
                    fs.WriteByte(textobyte);
                    pbProcess.PerformStep();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Arquivo gravado " + Path.GetFileName(nome));
            }
        }
        pbProcess.PerformStep();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    //}
    return true;
}
```

Error: ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected.

Tried Solution: Disable Managed Debug Assistants.

After disabling the MDA, the programs still only read-copy 31 files (of 5k).

Comment: After waiting 20 minutes, I have now 127 .Xml files, so I guess i'll just have to wait... but i'ts too heavy, even with a intel i7.

Comment: I could use File.copy to copy all the files, but i gonna need to read and write info at the end of the files. So i need to read all files... Sad.

Comment: As others suggested, use the `File.Copy` method to copy a file, reading an entire file and writing it to a different file is extremely inefficient. As for the waiting issue, it's because the reading/writing operation is being performed on the same thread that the GUI is running on. Put it in a `BackgroundWorker` and have that do the hard labor and update the progress bar.

Comment: I still recommand the use of File.Copy because its Highly optimized and not even a "real" C# Function but this is another story ... i will update my Solution

Comment: Solution is Updated ... code is non tested because i have no such xml documents

Comment: I'm gona use File.copy to put all files in the destination folder then I'm gonna use BackgroundWorker to read file per file to write aditional <tags>. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing i recommand is ... don't do that kind of file copy! use the [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function instead.

Try to use this code snipping from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx):

```
void DoCopy(string path)
{
    var copytask = new Task(() =>
    {
        string destinoComNomeArquivo = @"C:\" + Path.GetFileName(path);
        DirectoryCopy(path, destinoComNomeArquivo, false);
    });
    copytask.Start();
}

private void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
            "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
            + sourceDirName);
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
    }

    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
        file.CopyTo(temppath, false);                
    }

    var counter = 0;
    var maxcounter = files.Count();

    while (maxcounter < counter)
    {
        var item = files.ElementAt(counter).Name;
        WriteAsnc(item);
        counter++;
    }

    if (copySubDirs)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
            DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
        }
    }
}

const int _maxwritingprocess = Environment.ProcessorCount;
int _currentwritingtasks;

void WriteAsnc(string filepath)
{
    _currentwritingtasks++;
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
        doc.Elements().First().Add(new XAttribute("Attribute Name","Attribute Value"));
        doc.Save(filepath);
        _currentwritingtasks--;
    });
    if(_currentwritingtasks == _maxwritingprocess)
        task.Wait();
    _currentwritingtasks--;
}
```

The next point the `ContextSwitchDeadlock` is a Threading problem and i thing your `pbProcess` is the source. What does that Process do i don't see anything of that process and i don't thing it is Impotent for your copy

Comment: The biggest problem is: I still need to write things inside of the XML files, but now I'm gonna use a Backgroundworker to do the task.

Comment: This solution use a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) which is more efficient and recommend for using background operations (I will add a reference to the discussion later). This solution will enumerate all files in the Directory and move them to the new one. After that operation it will open all files and write your own XML attribute into it this happeds allso threaded so you can control your performance over the maxwritingprocess variable to get the best performance for your pc

Comment: [Using task instead of Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: Oh no, only for .net 4.5
I'm using 3.0... noooooo

Comment: [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd235604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is available till .net 4.0 that you really should use